# Laying things out relative to other elements (not RelativeLayout)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Is it possible to have values such as height, width and margins set by using, say, a percentage of another element's values. For example, having one element's width be half another one's.

I'm not bothered about when this is programmatically or in the axml code.

At the moment I've been trying to do it programmatically like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);

    var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
    var heightInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);

    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

                //Set title width as 98% of total width
    ImageView title_img = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.apptitle);
    LinearLayout baseparent = FindViewById<LinearLayout> (Resource.Id.baselayout);
    title_img.LayoutParameters.Width = (baseparent.Width / 100) * 98 ;
               //Set welcome width as half of title width
    ImageView welcome_img = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.welcome);
    welcome_img.LayoutParameters.Width = title_img.Width/2;
}


private int ConvertPixelsToDp(float pixelValue)
{
    var dp = (int) ((pixelValue)/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
    return dp;
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted seems allright to me. Can you explain why the code is not working? Or with it is doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to do this is to use `android:layout_weight` parameter in a linear layout. For example to have one element twice as big as the second one you can do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" />
    <LinearLayout android:background="#00FF00"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

A bit more on this can be found in the [article here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/297).